# How to turn Starcraft 2's IM off

Tags: starcraft-2, battle.net

Is there a way to turn Starcraft 2's built in instant messenger off and still play multiplayer games? Sometimes I don't want people bothering me while I'm playing.

Apologies if this is a dupe, this would seem to me that it's a common question, but the search yielded no results. Please close in this case.

Comment: Does setting your status to "busy" block incoming PMs?

Comment: @Raven No, it doesn't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting to busy (or away) is the best you can do. Your friends should honor that. Their IM system isn't extremely mature yet. Maybe they'll add features like this in time.

Comment: That's a bummer. Do you know if when you are set as busy or away if players can still see what you are doing?

Comment: I believe they can. REALID friends at least